# How to split 24 Hour time by 10 minutes

Tags: business-objects

I am trying to make a graph on BI which needs me to make so the time variable in my database groups for each 10 minutes IE - 11:04:00, 11:08:30, 11:00:28 are grouped as 11-1 then 11-2, ..., 11-6, 12-1 so on. -

```
06:00:00    06-1
06:03:00    
06:06:00    
06:09:00    
06:12:00    06-2
06:15:00    
06:18:00    
06:21:00    06-2
06:24:00    
06:27:00    
06:30:00    06-3
06:33:00    
06:36:00    
06:39:00    
06:42:00    06-4
06:45:00    
06:48:00    
06:51:00    06-5
06:54:00    
06:57:00    
07:00:00    07-1
07:03:00    
07:06:00    
07:09:00    
07:12:00    07-2
```

Is there anyway I can do this on the BI?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Is the source field really a date/time, or a string?

Comment: It's date&time object.

Comment: I don't understand the grouping logic.  The first two examples (06:00:00 = 06-1, and 06:12:00 = 06-2) imply that the block starts at 1 (that is, floor(minutes / 10) + 1).  But the remainder of the examples are all floor(minutes / 10).  Which is it?

Comment: @Joe no no i want the grouping with 10 minutes of intervals ; it can start from 6-0 i dont realy mind my point isnt the numbering. Just wanted to show i want different groups for different hours even at same minute separation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you 10-minute block groupings, starting with 0:

```
=FormatDate([Date];"HH")+"-"+Floor(ToNumber(FormatDate([Date];"mm"))/10)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for.